# Mongoose: how to use a schema field as an enum for another field?

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    possibleValues: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: { type: String, enum: possibleValues }
});
```

So possible values for "value" are the values in "possibleValues".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) that will check that `value` is contained within the doc's `possibleValues` array:

```js
var custom = [
    function(value) {
        // 'this' is the document being validated
        return this.possibleValues && this.possibleValues.indexOf(value) !== -1;
    },
    'value must be contained in possbileValues'
];

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    possibleValues: [String], // e.g. ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: { type: String, validate: custom }
});
```